# How to get name of superclass according to class in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, gnu-smalltalk

I know how to get a metaclass of a class in SMALLTALK `(with class message )`.

But how do i get  the `SuperClass` of a class (or get the `SuperClass` of an instance of some class )?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `instance class superclass` , of course!
Every class can answer its (unique) superclass.

However, note that you have several capitalization mistakes that are not innocent. In Smalltalk, capitalization rules are meaningful, beyond case-sensitivity.

Also, it is uncommon to cross the instance-class level to query something like this. Usually, only meta-programming tools (debuggers, inspectors) have questions like this.

Comment: So, the bottom-line answer is you can ask a `Class` instance which its `superclass` is. You first get your `Class` instance by sending `class` to your instance, and then send `superclass` to it's response.